# PyMongo - `If` doesn't work properly in cursor

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

I have a MongoDB and documents are like this:
[MongoDB collection Stucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKUc8.png)

I have a txt file that include some words and their sentiment scores.

I want to find these words in MongoDB but for certain relation, and I want to insert the fields of these documents in a new collection.

**Code:**

```
for w in words:
            print w
            cursor = db.collectionName.find({ 'surfaceStart': w })
        for document in cursor:
            relation = document['rel']
            word = document['surfaceEnd'].encode('utf-8')
            posnum = float(get_positive(cols))
            negnum = float(get_negative(cols))
            if (document['rel']).find('Synonym'):
                db.testcollection.insert ({ 'surfaceStart': w,'surfaceEnd': word,'Relation': relation, "pos": posnum, "neg": negnum })

            if (document['rel']).find('Antonym'):

                db.testcollection.insert ({ 'surfaceStart': w,'surfaceEnd': word,'Relation': relation, "pos": posnum, "neg": negnum })
            if (document['rel']).find('Related') or (document['rel']).find('Derived'):
                db.testcollection.insert ({ 'surfaceStart': w,'surfaceEnd': word,'Relation': relation, "pos": posnum, "neg": negnum })
```

Unfortunately, this code have a strange behavior.
It seems that there is no control about the relationship and inserts the document for every relationships, in the `testcollection`, 3 times.
I don't understand why that happens, as far as I have the IF functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document['rel']` appears to be a string: "r/instanceOf" in all the examples you posted. The `find` methods on strings returns the position of an item in the string, or -1 if it is not found; -1 is True in a boolean context.

You don't care about the position of the string anyway, so you shouldn't be using `find`. Use plain `in`:

```
if 'Synonym' in document['rel']:
    ...

if 'Related' in document['rel'] or 'Derived' in document['rel']:
```